# Short exact sequence of groups schemes and dimensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, torsion-groups

Let $G$ be a projective groups scheme over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$. Denote by $G_t$ the $p$-torsion part of $G$ i.e., elements $g \in G$ such that $g^p=0$. Is there any relation between the dimensions of $G$, $G_t$ and $G/G_t$? In particular, is $\dim(G/G_t)=\dim G-\dim G_t$?

Comment: If your finite flat connected group scheme over an algebraically closed field, then you're of $p$-power order. So, $G^\circ\subseteq G_t$ so $\dim G=\dim G^\circ\leqslant \dim G_t\leqslant \dim G$. EDIT: I noticed that you didn't say $p$-power torsion, but literal $p$-torsion. You should be able to modify my comment accordingly.